# What does "project" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What does "project" means in this context (emphasis mine)?

> Burke would have been especially wary of the Marxian idea of an ideological vanguard committed to the **project** of human liberties.

[image: The Moral Foundations of Politics by Ian Shapiro]

Answer (score 2):

"A plan or proposal for accomplishing something." [Freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/project)

"A proposal, scheme, or design." [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/project)

In this case the project (or plan, design) is meant to accomplish "human liberation".